# Remove hashtag from redirect with RewriteRule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm currently redirecting a URL by taking a variable and inserting it into a new URL. Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &pid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^vault/displayimage\.php$ photos/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately some links have a hashtag in the old system which aren't needed, so I'd like to redirect without them (or strip them off). Ex. - with the above redirect we take something like

```
/vault/displayimage.php?album=5&pid=10#top_pictures
```

which redirects to

```
/photos/10/#top_pictures
```

And I'd like it just to be

```
/photos/10/
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Location hashes exist only in the browser and are never sent to the server. Thus, you cannot influence them with rewrite rules.

That is one of the reasons why [people advise against using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340121/which-one-is-better-pushstate-or-location-hash).

See also [URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
RewriteRule ^vault/displayimage\.php$ photos/%1/#? [R=301,L,NE]
```

This works in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, but **not** in Firefox. I cannot test IE at the moment.

Also note that you end up with `#` in the url. This is better than `#top_pictures`, but not entirely clean.

The only way to really solve this is with some JavaScript.