# How to link a hash link from the URL to Javascript content?

Tags: javascript

I've once used jQuery UI in order to add the [tab feature](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to one of my project.

Everything was working just fine, and I noticed each tab was bound to a URL hash tag (I do not know you say it in english). As an example, once I clicked on the first tab, `#Tab0` was added to my URL.

I want to reproduce this behavior in my current project. But I'm not using jQuery UI tabs, I am porting a desktop application and there are JavaScript buttons which write and replace content inside my page (in the manner of different pages, but without reloading).

How do I proceed to mimic this behavior ? Do I have to manually fetch the tag in the URL and do things accordingly all by JavaScript ?

Thanks,

Comment: Also you can look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340121/which-one-is-better-pushstate-or-location-hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u could do it this way:

creating an url with hash from current url:

```
var url = window.location.href + '#Tab0';
```

reading a hash from current url:

```
var hash;

if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1)
{
    hash = url.split('#')[1];
}
```

Comment: So basically doing everything by hand. I will mark this as answered if I don't get anything else, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using `location.hash`:

```
//you can set hash
location.hash = "something"; 

//and read it eg. http://domain.com#something
console.log(location.hash); //will return the current hash value 'something'
```

Also you have to remember that if your anchor tag has hashed href attribute e.g. `<a href="#something">` it will be appended automatically to current url and browser will try to find given id on the page. Of course you can prevent that default behaviour.