# low cost page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to web development so this probably is a odd question. I want part of my site to load a new page. But significant part doen't need to change. What I do now is that I load content into a div.

```
$('#rightdiv').load("about.html");
```

The downside to this is that the address doesn't change, I believe there is a good solution but I don't know how. I have tried googleing it but I can't find anything good on it. So I would love to see both a solution and how the sollution is called (hope you know what I mean).

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Well you can find your own solution, its fairly easy. It is called 'HTML5 History API'. Google that.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll read this later today. (if you post is as an answer I might accept it as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers supporting HTML5's `pushState` will let you change the path:

```
$('#rightdiv').load("about.html", function pushState(){
    if(history && history.pushState){
        history.pushState('','','about.html');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use `location.hash`. So for example if you were on `mysite.com/`, and loaded the `about.html` page, you could set the hash to `#about`. This would not cause the page to reload, but would alter the URL (to provide for bookmark/back button support).

As an example, using the success callback to `load()`:

```
$('#rightdiv').load('about.html', function() {
    location.hash = 'about';
});
```

HTML5 adds a new API called `pushState`. This allows for more complete modification of the URL without causing a page reload. Read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: It takes more than that to support bookmark and back button.

Comment: This will get him started on the right path though.

Comment: `location.hash` was standard pre-HTML5, but `pushState` is probably preferable for new HTML5 development. See the competing answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340121/which-one-is-better-pushstate-or-location-hash), but take them with a grain of salt giving the dates of posting. See browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)

Comment: HTML5 isn't officially standardized yet. Soon, but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved by taking advantage of HTML5 and its features. 
Myspace does something similar to what you are asking. The HTML5 History API to change the browser URL without refreshing the page. Combining this with JQuery $.ajax can produce the effects shown in myspace, github and facebook. "arundavid" has a great explanation on this link at [tinywall.info](http://www.tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/)

Answer (score -1):

That's the right way to load data into a `div` using AJAX. I personally prefer to use the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function though.