# .htaccess redirect url and remove #591 from resulting url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've a backlink of my website as

```
http://localhost/babycare/article/detail/93#591
```

I want to redirect it to a new user-friendly url like

```
http://localhost/babycare/article/detail/feeding_aversion
```

The code i've written in my .htaccess file is here

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article/detail/93 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(babycare)? /article/detail/Feeding_Aversion? [R=301]
```

But it redirects to

```
http://localhost/babycare/article/detail/feeding_aversion#591
```

How could i remove #591 from url.

Comment: # is not part of server-side redirection as it's not sent to the server. You can use javascript to manipulate fregment.

Comment: but this code is written in .htaccess file. I want to remove it with regex if there is any method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that location hashes usually only exist in the browser, and are not meant to be handled by the server.

Its covering in more detail in the following answers;

[URL Fragment and 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects)

[Which one is better pushstate or location.hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340121/which-one-is-better-pushstate-or-location-hash)

---

You could use Javascript to remove the hash's if they're that much of an issue.

```
location.hash = "";
```

Should achieve what you're looking for - obviously it'll need to go onto each page.