# Can't go back after changing window.location.href

Tags: javascript, hash, window.location

In my script I'm tracking what tab I am on in a web page using

```
window.location.href = #!hashName1
```

If I then click on another tab, it will go to #!hashName2

My issue is, if I click the back button, it just goes back to the state #!hashName1. I have to then click back once again to go back another page.

Is there any way to just have it go back a page and not back to the previous hash state?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340140/4012073. I think that's what you need.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha I tried pushState -- it has the same issue

Comment: Maybe this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked perfectly:

I changed:

```
window.location.href = #!hashName1
```

to

```
history.replaceState("", "", #!hashName1);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can handle back button event like this

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
  goBack();
}

function goBack() {
    window.location.hash = window.location.lasthash[window.location.lasthash.length-1];
    //blah blah blah
    window.location.lasthash.pop();
}
```

Comment: 1. Wouldn't this be triggered every time the hash is changed?
2. Also, I don't think this would work if I click on multiple tabs (multiple hash updates)

Answer (score 0):

this will fire whenever you press back button and add previous url

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            window.location.href = document.referrer;
    }
```